# Wordpress as a frontend website for iOS app

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, database

I am developing a product for a local gym. The product comes in 2 parts : 
- a smartphone app used by the client 
- a website used by the coach

The coach uses the website to prepare the workout. So I need a good UI to allow him to create it. I can think a list of exercises from which he can selects the exercises, a form to set various parameters like the weight used for each set, etc.

So this data can contain integers, pictures, and text. On the other hand, the app fetches this data and works with it. That is, the user trains and records his perfs on the phone. At the end of the workout, the app sends the results back to the server, and the coach must be able to review it.

I have done an iOS app that deals successfully with the data and does its stuff during the training.

But I am struggling with the website since I do not know anything (almost) about web technologies. I looked into Wordpress as a mean to create both the front end and the server-database part.

I think that I need to create custom post types, like a type 'Exercise', a type 'Set', a type 'Workout' and custom meta boxes to let the coach configure the workout. But I do not know where to start.

Any guideline or advice would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: I will probably start by hiring someone to consult me and help me design the system. If you are not familiar with wordpress development then you are going to do many mistakes while getting the feel for it. It is not a problem if it is a hobby project, but this doesn't sound like one.

Comment: You can use the wordpress api. There is also a library for iOS for that. see https://github.com/evermeer/EVWordPressAPI

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't familiar with web technologies, you have a long road ahead of you.

That being said, if you have built an iOS app then you probably know something about programming and are willing to travel that road.

The best place to get started would probably be the [Wordpress Plugin Developers Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/)

If you can map the wanted functionality into custom post types and related taxonomies, then you could potentially create those needed, add any extra meta boxes, etc.